# Can this diagonal system be solved by modifying it to the $Ax=B$ form?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, tridiagonal-matrices, cyclic-decomposition

I'd like to use the $Ax=B$ form for solving the following system.
$$
    \left[
    \begin{matrix}
    t_0*d_0 & -t_1*e_0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & t_1*d_1 & -t_2*e_1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & t_2*d_2 & -t_3*e_2 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & t_3*d_3 & -t_4*e_3 \\
    \end{matrix}
    \right]
=
    \left[
    \begin{matrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    \end{matrix}
    \right]
$$
Where: $ t_n $ are variables. And $ d_{n} $ and $ e_{n} $ are constants.

Clearly this solves if all elements of $ \vec t = 0 $ but I'm looking for another solution, where one element of $ \vec t $ is constrained to a constant, say $t_1 = 20$.  Can this be done? Is $Ax=B$ even appropriate here?

Note: I'm revisiting a problem that could benefit from linear algebra after taking a very long hiatus. Apologies for missing obvious things.

Comment: Did you really mean $\left( \begin{array}{ccccc} d_0 & -e_0 & 0 &0 & 0 \\ 0 & d_1 & -e_1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 &0 & d_2 & -e_2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & d_3 & -e_3 \end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{c} t_1 \\ t_2 \\ t_3 \\ t_4 \end{array} \right) = \left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{array} \right)$ ? The way you wrote it doesn't make sense, because the left side of the equation is a matrix, and the right side is a vector.

Comment: Quite possibly! 
My original system of equations is
$
    \begin{matrix}
    t_0*d_0 - t_1*e_0 = 0 \\
    t_1*d_1 - t_2*e_1 = 0 \\
    t_2*d_2 - t_3*e_2 = 0 \\
    t_3*d_3 - t_4*e_3 = 0 \\
    \end{matrix}
$
Isn't what you wrote equivalent to this? And isn't the matrix in the post the same thing as well, but aligned so that all t_n reside in their respective columns?

Comment: Assuming the form I'm after is this,

$$
    \left[
    \begin{matrix}
    d_0 & -e_0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & d_1 & -e_1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & d_2 & -e_2 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & d_3 & -e_3 \\
    \end{matrix}
    \right]
 \left[
    \begin{matrix}
    t_0 \\
    20 \\
    t_2 \\
    t_3 \\
 t_4 \\
    \end{matrix}
    \right]
=
    \left[
    \begin{matrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    \end{matrix}
    \right]
$$

How do I deal with that constant $ t_1 = 20 $ when solving $ \vec t = A^{-1} * B $ in something like Octave or Matlab?

Comment: And here's one of the obvious things I could be presenting incorrectly. Are the following two representations drastically different in meaning?

$$
    \left[
    \mathbf A
    \right]
 \left[
    \mathbf t
    \right]
=
    \left[
 \mathbf B
    \right]
$$

and

$$
    \left(
    \mathbf A
    \right)
 \left(
    \mathbf t
    \right)
=
    \left(
    \mathbf B
    \right)
$$

Comment: No. They are exactly the same. It is simply a matter of personal taste whether people like to use square brackets or round brackets for matrices and vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do simple "back-substitution". The last equation is equivalent to $t_3 = \frac{e_3}{d_3} t_4$. Then the third equation gives $t_2 = \frac{e_2}{d_2} t_3 = \frac{e_2 e_3}{d_2 d_3} t_4$. Keep repeating to write all the variables $t_1,t_2,t_3$ as multiples of $t_4$.

Comment: I like that! And appreciate your attention on this, Nick. I would definitely back-substitute by hand on a system this small. I probably should have mentioned that this was a tiny representation of a larger system, like $$t_n, \; where \; n \gt 1000$$

I am hoping to understand this in a way that would allow me to programmatically plug a large set of $ d_n $ and $ e_n $ values in to something like GNU Octave. 


But first-things-first. I hope to understand if this can fit into the $Ax=B$ format so that I can use Octave's standard x = linsolve (A, b) function.

Comment: Considering how I presented the question, this is a fine answer by @Nick . Now that I am more clear about what I need to ask on a forum for this, I've created a more concise question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3225979/is-this-the-ax-b-form-for-the-following-system-of-equations)