# Is this the $Ax=B$ form for the following system of equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Here's the system of equations:
$$
    \begin{matrix}
    t_0*d_0 & -t_1*e_0 = 0 \\
    t_1*d_1 & -t_2*e_1 = 0 \\
    t_2*d_2 & -t_3*e_2 = 0 \\
    t_3*d_3 & -t_4*e_3 = 0 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$
Where: $ t_i $ are variables. And $ d_{n} $ and $ e_{n} $ are coefficients .

Does this $Ax=B$ form represent the system accurately?
$$
    \left[
    \begin{matrix}
    d_0 & -e_0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & d_1 & -e_1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & d_2 & -e_2 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & d_3 & -e_3 \\
    \end{matrix}
    \right]
 \left[
    \begin{matrix}
    t_0 \\
    t_1 \\
    t_2 \\
    t_3 \\
 t_4 \\
    \end{matrix}
    \right]
=
    \left[
    \begin{matrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    \end{matrix}
    \right]
$$

Also, is this the correct form for a horizontally augmented matrix?
$$
    \left[
    \begin{array}{ccccc|c}
    t_0*d_0 & -t_1*e_0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
    0 & t_1*d_1 & -t_2*e_1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
    0 & 0 & t_2*d_2 & -t_3*e_2 & 0 & 0  \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & t_3*d_3 & -t_4*e_3 & 0  \\
    \end{array}
    \right]
$$
Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: There’s usually not much point to augmenting the coefficient matrix for a homogeneous system of equations this way. No matter what row operations you perform on it, the last column will always consist of zeros.